# odoo, custom module margin ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, module, odoo

I'm a odoo 13 user (not developer).
I'm try to create a custom module for to show product margin percent, in purchase order line.
I've copy module code from default Odoo sale_margin addon, and I've adapt it for my custom module.
In Purchase Order, when I add product, edit qty or product price value, I have error:
margin = ((price - line.price_unit) / price) * 100
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Please, can someone help me to solve this issue?
Below code,
Thanks

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
import odoo.addons.decimal_precision as dp

class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'

    margin = fields.Float(string='Margin (%)', compute='_product_margin', digits='Product Price', store=True)
    sale_price = fields.Float(string='Price', digits='Product Price')

    def _compute_margin(self, order_id, product_id, product_uom_id):
        sale_price = product_id.lst_price
        if product_uom_id != product_id.uom_id:
            sale_price = product_id.uom_id._compute_price(sale_price, product_uom_id)

    @api.model
    def _get_sale_price(self, product, product_uom):
        sale_price = product.lst_price
        if product_uom != product.uom_id:
            sale_price = product.uom_id._compute_price(sale_price, product_uom)

    @api.onchange('product_id', 'product_uom')
    def product_id_change_margin(self):
        if not self.product_id or not self.product_uom:
            return
        self.sale_price = self._compute_margin(self.order_id, self.product_id, self.product_uom)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        vals.update(self._prepare_add_missing_fields(vals))

        # Calculation of the margin for programmatic creation of a PO line. It is therefore not
        # necessary to call product_id_change_margin manually
        if 'sale_price' not in vals and ('display_type' not in vals or not vals['display_type']):
            order_id = self.env['sale.order'].browse(vals['order_id'])
            product_id = self.env['product.product'].browse(vals['product_id'])
            product_uom_id = self.env['uom.uom'].browse(vals['product_uom'])

            vals['sale_price'] = self._compute_margin(order_id, product_id, product_uom_id)

        return super(SaleOrderLine, self).create(vals)

    @api.depends('product_id', 'sale_price', 'product_uom', 'price_unit', 'price_subtotal')
    def _product_margin(self):
        for line in self:
            price = line.sale_price
            margin = ((price - line.price_unit) / price) * 100
            line.margin = margin
```

Comment: price = line.sale_price maybe 0  check price == 0 then set margin to 0 else calculate or use this module that may do something similar https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/sales_margin_percentage/

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf add this as an answer ;-)

Comment: Hi Muhammad Yusuf, thank you very much for your help. I'm sorry for this long time, but I was busy. I've adapt module you was suggested, it work. Last problem I need to solve, I have lst price wiith tax included, and I don't know how get it tax excluded. Thanks